# How to read/write cookie for a different domain (.net core )

Tags: asp.net-core, cross-domain, asp.net-core-webapi

whats the simple way to set a cookie for a different domain ?

this is how i set the cookie :

```
CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions()
        {
            Expires = dateTimeOffset
            ,
            Domain = domain

            ,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
            ,
            HttpOnly = false
            ,
            Path = "/"

        };

        httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, cookieOptions);
```

I thought SameSite = `SameSiteMode.None` will do the job

iam guessing its not

Comment: I'm sorry but it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies) without cors policies

Comment: That's not possible. The browser prevents it

Comment: i think i miss understood 
what i want to do is to store a cookie on a different domain from the request domain

this is possible

"cross domain cookie"